# In Extjs, Need one Global combo box class for different instances of different json data

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

How to use  same xtype combo box for different json data at different places?

Answer (score 0):

The data in a combobox is determined by the `store` config item you specify while creating the combobox. In the following example:

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
    xtype: 'combo',
    store: states //Change your store here 
    }],
    .....
});
```

While creating comboboxes in different places, just give the reference to a different store and the data loaded in that combo would be based on how you instantiate that store. Look up the [api here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) for more information